# Clojure: having difficulty applying protocol to 2 types successfully

Tags: clojure, protocols, clojurescript, lighttable, deftype

`Other` is a more complex version (wrapping) of `What`.  It does what `What` does but much more.  I took care to define 2 namespaces.

```
(ns what)

(defprotocol IWhatever
  (whatever [this]))

(deftype What []
  IWhatever
  (whatever [this]
            (str "whatever")))

(whatever (->What))

(ns other (:require what))

(deftype Other []
  what/IWhatever
  (whatever [this]
            (what/whatever (what/->What))))

(whatever (->Other)) ;bad line
```

The error is:

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: whatever in this context, compiling:(C:\...)
```

Why won't this last expression resolve?  It's like the name can't be found, but as you can see I redefined it under the current namespace.

It's nonsense code but I used the simplest example of the problem to illustrate the point.  I'm running this in LightTable if that's relevant.

Comment: When calling the protocol function, you need to use a qualified symbol, i.e. `(dict/get man :name)` instead of `(get man :name)`.

Comment: It won't call the Dictionary version, since the version in Dictionary doesn't have implementation. Try it in repl and see for yourself.

Comment: @Mario I think you're missing the point of protocols. A protocol defines a set of polymorphic functions. You call a protocol function, and it dispatches based on the type of the first argument. If you had to call a different function for each implementing type, it would defeat the whole purpose.

Comment: What happens in the REPL when you call `dict/get` on an `Item`? Have you tried that yet?

Comment: I moved all the code to one file and reduced it to it's simplest form to better illustrate the point.

Comment: Again: have you tried my original suggestion of using a namespace-qualified call to `what/whatever` from your `other` namespace?

Comment: The call won't resolve because `extend-type` doesn't define new functions in the current namespace. It adds functions to the dispatch table of the protocol being extended.

Comment: @Mario it doesn't resolve cause **you have to qualify** the function from the protocol if the protocol is in another namespace. **try** `(what/whatever oth)` and convince yourself.

Comment: It worked for me without problems. You sure you didn't redefine things somewhere along the way?

Comment: @Mario I just copied and pasted your code into light table. As is it gives the error you mention. Adding the what/ that soulcheck suggests works for me.  You might want to try it again with a clean environment.

Comment: The code in the screenshot you posted is different from your sample above. There, `(what/wht)` is attempting to call an object of type `What` as a function, and it's not a function. That exception (a) is different than the exception posted above, and (b) happens to be thrown from inside the function that you claim not to be able to call.

Comment: I finally got it.  Thanks for all your time.  SO appreciative.

Comment: @Mario, instead of editing the question with the answer, could you post the answer below and accept it? That's a perfectly valid thing to do here. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Qualify the final line with the namespace of where the protocol was defined.  I kept thinking to try to call the `whatever` method in the `other` namespace since it was defined there.

```
(what/whatever (->Other))
```

Thanks goes to @soulcheck and everyone else who took time to help.